# Spring boot @DateTimeFormat on required query parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, date-formatting

When using @DateTimeFormat annotation to format a date sent as query parameter (@RequestParam), it automatically converts empty strings (received as date) to null without throwing type mismatch exception. This works fine when a date parameter is optional, however, when required = true is set, the @DateTimeFormat accepts the empty string and converts it to null without throwing an exception thus the required = true spring attribute is not considered. Is this a normal behavior from Spring? Are there any attributes that we can pass to  @DateTimeFormat to choose if empty strings are acceptable or not?

```
@RequestParam(required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd") Date inputDate
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce your issues with the following code with spring boot 2.4.4:

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String demo(@RequestParam(required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date inputDate) {
   System.out.println("inputDate: " + inputDate);
   return inputDate.toString();
}
```

1. The url `http://localhost:8080/?inputDate=2021-03-01` gives `Mon Mar 01 00:00:00 CET 2021` in the browser
2. The url `http://localhost:8080/?inputDate=` and `http://localhost:8080/`gives `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).`in the browser and `Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Date parameter 'inputDate' is not present]` in the log
3. The url `http://localhost:8080/?inputDate=x` gives `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).` in the browser and `Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'` in the log.

From your question I understand this is what you want.

Can you please clearify if I have misunderstood your question or else see if your can reproduce my result and see if they give the behaviour you want?

Comment: I am using 2.2.0.RELEASE and your code with this path: http://localhost:8080/?inputDate=   returns inputDate: null which means that the required true did not work

Comment: Strenge... Could you just to test it upgrade spring-boot-starter-paren to 2.2.4 to see if that makes any difference. Can it be any other settings in you project? Just to be sure you could try with a fresh project from https://start.spring.io/. Which javaversion are you seeing this issue with. I tried with jdk11.

Comment: I tried on a separate application it worked for both spring versions, maybe it is a property under my project. Is there anything that can affect this behavior?

Comment: i am using java 8

Comment: Good to hear it worked in a separate application. You could start to check your ```application.properties``` for things that seems relevant in any way. You could also try to delete all content of ```application.properties``` and see if that helps. If it does, you could add  things bit for bit and see when it breaks to identify the troublemaker.

Comment: Confirmed. Issue is related to Spring version. The first time i tried Maven was not fully sync. If you switch between Spring versions, the issue is reproduced without adding any property of settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `java.time.LocalDate` without any `@DateTimeFormat`.

`java.util.Date` is outdated and `java.time.*` is intended to replace it.

`LocalDate` uses the ISO8601 format by default, and it is matched with your 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
Also, its parse method throws an exception on an empty string.